# Reversing (or simplifying) a Cartesian product?

Tags: python-2.7, cartesian-product, radix-tree

To make things easier but also more complicated, I tried to implement a concept of "*combined / concise tags*" that expand further on into multiple basic tag forms.

In this case the tags consist of (one or more) "sub-tag(s)", delimited by semicolons:

```
food:fruit:apple:sour/sweet

drink:coffee/tea:hot/cold

wall/bike:painted:red/blue
```

Slashes indicate "sub-tag" interchangeability.
Therefore the interpreter translates them to this:

```
food:fruit:apple:sour
food:fruit:apple:sweet

drink:coffee:hot
drink:coffee:cold
drink:tea:hot
drink:tea:cold

wall:painted:red
wall:painted:blue
bike:painted:red
bike:painted:blue
```

The code used (not perfect, but works):

```
import itertools

def slash_split_tag(tag):
    if not '/' in tag:
        return tag
    subtags = tag.split(':')
    pattern, v_pattern = (), ()
    for subtag in subtags:
        if '/' in subtag:
            pattern += (None,)
            v_pattern += (tuple(subtag.split('/')),)
        else:
            pattern += (subtag,)
    def merge_pattern_and_product(pattern, product):
        ret = list(pattern)
        for e in product:
            ret[ret.index(None)] = e
        return ret
    CartesianProduct = tuple(itertools.product(*v_pattern)) # http://stackoverflow.com/a/170248
    return [ ':'.join(merge_pattern_and_product(pattern, product)) for product in CartesianProduct ]

#===============================================================================
# T E S T
#===============================================================================

for tag in slash_split_tag('drink:coffee/tea:hot/cold'):
    print tag
print
for tag in slash_split_tag('A1/A2:B1/B2/B3:C1/C2:D1/D2/D3/D4/EE'):
    print tag
```

**Question: How can I possibly revert this process? I need this for readability reasons.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple, first-pass attempt at such a function:

```
def compress_list(alist):
    """Compress a list of colon-separated strings into a more compact
    representation.
    """
    components = [ss.split(':') for ss in alist]

    # Check that every string in the supplied list has the same number of tags
    tag_counts = [len(cc) for cc in components]
    if len(set(tag_counts)) != 1:
        raise ValueError("Not all of the strings have the same number of tags")

    # For each component, gather a list of all the applicable tags. The set
    # at index k of tag_possibilities is all the possibilities for the
    # kth tag
    tag_possibilities = list()
    for tag_idx in range(tag_counts[0]):
        tag_possibilities.append(set(cc[tag_idx] for cc in components))

    # Now take the list of tags, and turn them into slash-separated strings
    tag_possibilities_strs = ['/'.join(tt) for tt in tag_possibilities]

    # Finally, stitch this together with colons
    return ':'.join(tag_possibilities_strs)
```

Hopefully the comments are sufficient in explaining how it works. A few caveats, however:

- It doesn't do anything sensible such as escaping backslashes if it finds them in the list of tags.
- This doesn't recognise if there's a more subtle division going on, or if it gets an incomplete list of tags. Consider this example:

  ```
  fish:cheese:red
  chips:cheese:red
  fish:chalk:red
  ```

  It won't realise that only `cheese` has both `fish` and `chips`, and will instead collapse this to `fish/chips:cheese/chalk:red`.
- The order of the tags in the finished string is random (or at least, I don't think it has anything to do with the order of the strings in the given list). You could sort `tt` before you join it with slashes if that's important.

Testing with the three lists given in the question seems to work, although as I said, the order may be different to the initial strings:

```
food:fruit:apple:sweet/sour
drink:tea/coffee:hot/cold
wall/bike:painted:blue/red
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I wanted. Sorting and input parsing is not the issue here. I just couldn't figure out all the combinations. So, base element count has to be equal, then just merge column-wise. Thanks for your time and happy new year;]